# One style for two different shapes

Tags: wpf

I have a Rectangle and an Ellipse shape in a user control, both of which have the same styling.

```
<Style x:Key="StyleEllipse" TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

<Style x:Key="StylePolygon" TargetType="Polygon">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
```

Ellipse and Polygon both inherit from System.Windows.Shapes, so is it possible to create a single style that both could use, rather than having two styles that are essentially the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Style can have Shape as TargetType:

```
<Style x:Key="ShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>

...
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource ShapeStyle}" ... />
<Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ShapeStyle}" ... />
```